# How to filter Outlook events by content

Tags: microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to get a list of Outlook events over the Graph API and filter them by searching for some text in the events body.

I was able to filter by subject like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=contains(subject,'test')
```

But if I try this with the body it does not work. The returned error message is either 'Invalid filter clause' or it says that an internal server error occurred. I understand that the body property of the event is not of type string, but it should be possible somehow to search in its content property

I already tried the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=contains(body,'test')
```

This returns 'Invalid filter clause'

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=contains(body/content,'test')
```

Returns 'An internal server error occurred'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Microsoft Graph does not support filtering for the field body